# Wordpress Edit Page not working

Tags: wordpress

I am running on the latest version of wordpress.

I am clicking on edit page of a Home Page, however, wordpress is not allowing me to edit the page.

also when clicking on edit post, the font is white on the visual editor and this is very frustrating.

So kindly please help.

Comment: may i knoow which version you have?

Comment: Question is not clear, more details please or screenshot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step to perform**

1. Deactivate all plugins. Yes... ALL plugins.
2. Switch to the default 2014 theme.
3. Manually empty and refresh your browser cache.

Only after you perform all three steps.. will you see the content editor load properly.

**Why need to do this step**

1. You have to deactivate all plugins to rule out possible interference from a plugin.
2. You have to switch to the default theme because... well... we know it works.
3. You have to manually empty your browser cache because the tinymce editor is notorious for holding onto and serving cached files from the server.

Now, after your editor is working properly again... reactivate your theme.

If it continues working... it's not your theme. Begin reactivating plugins (one at a time) going back to check the editor.

You will eventually find the faulty plugin (or theme) that is preventing the editor from displaying properly.

**"Edit Page" - all of the text in the edit box is in white font**

Try adding `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` to the bottom of your wp-config.php file (just before the require_once line).

Comment: Awesome! i disabled the plugins and it i now am able to view the 'edit page'.. great! thanks Vasim

Comment: the problem is with the theme.. when i switch back to the default theme..it works..